# Re-sizing background images with mobile parallax and CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image, parallax

I'm trying very hard to resize my background images with my personal website: calebcharles.com.
I can't tell if this is something that needs to be done with a background-size: fix in CSS or if I need to create alternate images for media-query based fixes. I'm a new designer so please go easy! I'd sincerely appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Here is an example of one of the sections of my site:

h1.slide1 {

```
padding-top: 10%;
    color: white;
    background-image: url("images/rainbow.jpg");
    background-position: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 400%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

full site is www.calebcharles.com. The backgrounds look awful on mobile devices. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a background that is spread to 100%. The background itself is a widescreen `1920x730` image while mobile resolutions are generally portrait.

Look into media queries and have multiple background resolutions pre-rendered.

```
.slide1 {
    background-image: url('images/rainbow.jpg');
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
   .slide1 {
        background-image: url('images/rainbow-768.jpg');
    }
}

@media (min-width:1920px) {
   .slide1 {
        background-image: url('images/rainbow-1920.jpg');
    }
}

@media (min-width:2560px) {
   .slide1 {
        background-image: url('images/rainbow-2560.jpg');
    }
}
```

Comment: AH! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for the advice. I didn't consider the portrait component.